# Как перенести скрипт из шаблона в плагин WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Есть скрипт который создает кастомные поля пользователя в админке WordPress, они выводятся через function.php в шаблоне. Переношу в function.php плагина, не работает, почему так может быть, может там нужно как-то по другому?

```
// когда пользователь сам редактирует свой профиль
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'true_show_profile_fields' );
// когда чей-то профиль редактируется админом например
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'true_show_profile_fields' );
 
function true_show_profile_fields( $user ) {
 
    // выводим заголовок для наших полей
    echo '<h3>Дополнительная информация</h3>';
 
    // поля в профиле находятся в рамметке таблиц <table>
    echo '<table class="form-table">';
 
    // добавляем поле пол
    // также можно и установить значение по умолчанию
    $gender = ( $gender = get_the_author_meta( 'gender', $user->ID ) ) ? $gender : 'male';
    echo '<tr><th><label for="gender">Пол</label></th>
        <td><select>
            <option value="male" name="gender"' . selected( $gender, 'male', false ) . '>male</option>
            <option value="female" name="gender"' . selected( $gender, 'female', false ) . '>female</option>
            <option value="other" name="gender"' . selected( $gender, 'other', false ) . '>other</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>';
 
    echo '</table>';
 
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Духсообщества Разошёлся наш дух сообщества не на шутку. Вопрос ясен и понятен тем, кто занимается WordPress.

Comment: Что за "function.php плагина"? Код должен быть в плагине. https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: Ошибочка. Да, тело самого плагина, главный файл где пишется название, описание, версия и т.п. Туда так же вставляю этот скрипт и он не пашет, а если в function шаблона, работает

Comment: Значит ты что-то не то делаешь. Вот результат работы плагина по твоему коду  https://i.imgur.com/kVvjwGN.jpeg

Comment: тоже заработало, спасибо. Просто плагин нужно было выключить и обратно включить. Какая связь, хз, но заработало